# Como remover URL após carregamento?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho minha URL

www.site.com/produto/link/codigo/1

Após carregar, eu gostaria que não aparecesse a URL no navegador, apenas www.site.com

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Este comando JavaScript limpa a URL mantendo apenas o domínio:

```
window.history.pushState("", "", "/");
```

Ficará registrado no histórico de navegação porque é para isso na verdade que serve este comando (usamos este recurso para incluir uma requisição Ajax no histórico de navegação e para permitir o compartilhamento da URL de uma página com estado alterado via AJAX).

Outra forma seria: em vez de o usuário obter esta página por um link, obter por um `POST`, então a resposta do POST é uma nova página sem *redirect* (a URL permanecerá a mesma).

Não conheço sua necessidade específica, então segue uma opinião: um bom aplicativo web sempre dá ao usuário a experiência de estar navegando entre páginas e através de links. Mesmo que o aplicativo seja um maravilhoso *single page* como o GMail ou algo próximo disso como o Facebook, o usuário vai gostar de poder navegar pelo histórico, salvar páginas nos favoritos e compartilhar URLs. Se o aplicativo usa do recurso que descrevi (retornar página através de POST), o usuário tem a experiência de uso prejudicada.

Comment: Em uma aplicação comercial, por exemplo, um Erp, não vejo a necessidade dele ficar navegando com as URLs, além de evitar erros, por exemplo ele passa um Id no Editar que não existe...etc Aí por isso que eu quis remover a url

Comment: Minha opinião né Caffé, mas concordo com você na sua opinião também, casos e casos

Comment: Entendo. Eu particularmente vejo benefício sim mesmo num ERP. O *back button* é um conceito importante na navegação web. Mantendo o aplicativo inteiro na mesma URL você tira esse recurso dos usuários. Você terá que se preocupar com Ids e URLs válidos, mas depois de tratar umas 3 páginas você vê que isso não acrescenta muito esforço de programação. Eu penso no cara da contabilidade investigando uma Nota Fiscal, como seria bacana poder salvá-la nos favoritos em vez de dar meia dúzia de cliques toda vez que quiser voltar a ela. Também seria bacana compartilhar a nota enviando uma URL por email.

Comment: É, faz sentido sim, é que estou tendo problema com uma forma de criar vinculos com determinada entidade, até fiz uma pergunta sobre isso...to tentando resolver de N formas, mas não consigo imaginar e evitar erros