# Como remover parâmetro da URL ao clicar em um âncora com link interno?

Tags: javascript

Após clicar em um link interno para ir à um local na página a URL acrescenta no final #first-section que é o `href` da âncora que cliquei. Como posso remover da URL usando Javascript puro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa URL que se refere seria a URL exibida na barra de endereços ou seria outra URL?

Comment: @AugustoVasques É a URL da barra de endereço

Comment: De uma olhada nesse método: [`History.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como remover URL após carregamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38276/como-remover-url-ap%c3%b3s-carregamento)

Comment: @AugustoVasques ainda não é oque procuro... vou atualizar o post com uma imagem

Comment: É isso sim, `window.history.pushState("", "", "/");` ou `window.history.replaceState("", "", "/");`

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu já resolvi esse problema a muito tempo mas não me lembro como, já tentei usar o event.preventDefault()

Comment: @AugustoVasques Nesse caso eu só consegui substituir o "/" por nada mas ainda continua com o parâmetro porém sem o "/"

Answer (score -1):

Ao clicar no link chame uma função para setar o Hash e apagar

```
Function hashSemHash(e) {

history.pushState("", document.title, location.pathname)

e.preventDefault()
}
```